# undo edited files in eclipse remote systems

Tags: eclipse, remote-server

I use Eclipse Remote Systems to connecto to remote Projects. I have edited one html file in Eclipse Remote Systems and saved and closed the edited file. Is there any possibility to undo the changes in this file?

Comment: Have you tried Restore from Local History Option?
http://www.nodans.com/index.cfm/2008/1/18/How-to-recover-a-deleted-file-in-Eclipse

Comment: This option is not available. It is about remote system/server